# Find number of block io per process

Tags: linux

How i can find the number of blocks read by my program. The `iostat` and `iotop` is not my solution. I want the actual number of blocks read.
Is it equal to page fault counts that earned from `/usr/bin/time` command?

My Problem is:

I have a program (BLAST) that search a query in a file (using memory-mapped files). I run it in two orders.The first order is faster but has more page faults. I can't understand why?

Comment: try `iosnoop -p <PID>`